# Get other coefficient estimates in rdrobust function output

Tags: r

Using the rdrobust function from rdrobust package in R, I only get the treatment estimate. I am not able to get estimates for other covariates in the regression:

`est2 <- rdrobust(y=vote, x=margin, covs=cbind(class,termshouse,termssenate))`

I have tried all the codes like these:
`est2$z`
`est2$Estimate`
`est2$coef`
`est2$beta_p_l`
`est2$beta_p_r`

**Please help, I am stuck for many days.** I have surfed all over the internet but could not find anything.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.